# file_put_contents in php

Tags: php

I just tried to use this `file_put_contents`. 
The code is:

```
$file = 'list.txt';
$subject = "Mail Subject\n";
file_put_contents($file, $subject);
```

But it doesn’t put any contents. `file_get_contents` is working though.

**Update: Problem solved. I’m not sure. I just changed chmod to 777. But I have a doubt. I am checking the log error.**

Comment: Check the return value of file_put_contents. if it's boolean false, then something's wrong (probably permissions-related).

Comment: What does your error log say?  Could be a file permission issue.

Comment: -1. You did not post any error message. It is another _wont work, guess why_ question.

Comment: No error showing . But it can't put contents.

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

- Your file path is relative.  So your file may not be in the directory you think it is.
- Check that you have permission to create files in the directory containing your file, or that you have permissions to overwrite the existing file.
- Finally, `file_put_contents` returns the number of bytes written or false on error.  Save the return value to a variable and see what you get back.